# Listing AWS S3 buckets using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the PHP AWS SDK and would like to list all buckets available to me in S3.

I found a few different blocks of documentation that look promising:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_bucket_list
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.Iterator.ListBucketsIterator.html

Here's what I'm trying, using the [AWS Service Builder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html) to initialize an S3 client...

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;

// Instantiate an S3 client
$aws = Aws::factory(array( 'key' => "MY_KEY", 'secret' => "MY_SECRET"));
$s3 = $aws->get('s3');
$s3->get_bucket_list();
```

Unfortunately when I run the code I am told that it has no freakin' clue what "get_buckets_list" is.  More specifically it says

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command was not found matching GetBucketList' in vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php:87
```

So my questions are as follows:

- Am I looking at the wrong documentation?
- Is there other documentation somewhere?
- How do you get a list of buckets using the PHP AWS SDK?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation for this call can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listBuckets).

```
$result = $s3->listBuckets(array());
foreach ($result['Buckets'] as $bucket) {
    echo $bucket['Name'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

I suspect that you were mixing up two different API's :)

Comment: Having worked at AWS on both SDK 1.x and SDK 2.x, this is the correct answer. You were trying to use v1 code and v2 code together. The second documentation link is what you should be referring to... not the first one.

Comment: Oh perfect!  Thank you -- and yes, I had a feeling something was up.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to actually do this, but I got here by reverse engineering rather than actually discovering proper documentation.  Therefore I consider this to only be a partial answer.

This code will iterate through your buckets and output each name.

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;

// Instantiate an S3 client
$aws = Aws::factory(array( 'key' => "MY_KEY", 'secret' => "MY_SECRET"));
$s3 = $aws->get('s3');
$s3->get_bucket_list();

$iterator = $s3->getIterator('ListBuckets');
foreach ($iterator as $bucket) {
    echo $bucket['Name'] . "\n";
}
```